# Getting a CSS calc percentage result

Tags: css, calc

I am trying to derive some responsive CSS, that gracefully resizes an image element.

Within one range (`@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 960px)`) I want the *percentage width property* of my image to vary.

Specifically, at 960, I want it to effectively be `width: 50%`, but down at 600, I want it to effectively be `width: 38.1966%`. For every pixel of width reduction, the width I need decreases by 0.032787%.

So far, I have found no way to get `calc()` to handle this.

I effectively need to first perform a basic calculation: `(960px - 100vw)`. Unfortunately, this gives a result in pixels, whereas I need it converted to a number, that I can multiply by my target percentage variance.

Is it even possible?

Comment: does it have to be only css? can you use jQuery?

Comment: I gave the answer via CSS only - but this could be done much easier via something like LESS if you were willing to try that. http://lesscss.org/ - specifically the language features / operations view: http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to use jQuery:

Once you have the calculated value in css like you mentioned, you get get it with `var itemWidth = $('#id').innerWidth();`. Then, you can get the width of the page with `var bodyWidth = $('body').innerWidth();`

So, you can write a script that uses `bodyWidth` and `itemWidth` to calculate a percentage `var percentVar= itemWidth / bodyWidth * 100;` and use that to set the width of an item `$("#id").css("width", percentVar);`.

So, the jQuery would look something along these lines:

```
var main = function(){
    var itemWidth = $('#id').innerWidth();
    var bodyWidth = $('body').innerWidth();
    var percentVar= itemWidth / bodyWidth * 100;
    $("#id").css("width", percentVar);
}

$(document).ready(main)
```

Or, if you were to want to reuse it, make a function and put that in the main function

```
var main = function(){
    element_sizer('#id');
    element_sizer('#id2');
}

$(document).ready(main)    

function element_sizer(id) {
    var itemWidth = $(id).innerWidth();
    var bodyWidth = $('body').innerWidth();
    var percentVar= itemWidth / bodyWidth * 100;
    $(id).css("width", percentVar);
}
```

Note: you can use `width`, `innerWidth`, `outerWidth` depending on what you need [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_width.asp)

Comment: Unfortunately, this contaminates the client-side code with inline css. And while everyone else seems to think that's just fine, I see it as a breath away from table-based layouts. (I figure adjusting to to link on a class rather than id wouldn't be an issue - there's a stack of elements in there.)
I also forgot to mention… no jQuery.

Comment: @Rick good luck then, I don't think you can do it with pure css

Comment: Thanks. I thought as much - they left out the really fun stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Pure CSS.. this is honestly a mess but it will work:

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/r9xwL0rb/

CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 960px){img{width: 50%;}}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 959px){img{width: 49.96721278%;}}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 958px){img{width: 49.93442556%;}}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 957px){img{width: 49.90163833%;}}
... etc (see fiddle for complete source)
```

Comment: Thanks @remixdesign, I suppose that really is about it. (Though they can technically be clustered in groups of 3-5; by the time you're down to 40%, as a 0.2% difference is required to change the width by a pixel.) But agreed - damned messy.

Comment: You're welcome - Minor update (not nesting the media queries inside the main one - that was an oversight.) Created a fiddle for you! Please accept answer if it helps!